# How can I merge multiple text files into one data.frame?

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe

Suppose I have 9 .txt files in the same directory.
price1.txt price2.txt price3.txt is a table of price from different location, row and col name is longitude and altitude correspondingly. 
year4,5,6.txt and dis7,8,9.txt is a table of year and discount from the same location as in text1.

I want to create a new data frame where each column is a list of a price, year, discount from text 1-9 with the corresponding longitude and attitude.

I was able to use

```
mydata = list.files(pattern = "\\.txt$")
```

to read the names of the files

I was able to use

```
a = lapply(mydata, read.table, header = TRUE)
```

to have put together each files.

But how can I extract the table from different variable text files and put them into a column? The difficult part here is that all file names are different so I cant figure out a simple way to loop the list of files.

Answer (score 1):

Consider reading in price, year, disc text files into their own dataframes then merging:

```
pricelist <- list.files(pattern = "price-.*\\.txt")
pricedf <- lapply(pricelist, read.table, header=TRUE)

yearlist <- list.files(pattern = "year-.*\\.txt")
yeardf <- lapply(yearlist, read.table, header=TRUE)

disclist <- list.files(pattern = "disc-.*\\.txt")
discdf <- lapply(disclist, read.table, header=TRUE)

finaldf <- merge(pricedf, yeardf, by=c("longitude", "altitude"))
finaldf <- merge(finaldf, discdf, by=c("longitude", "altitude"))
```

For a generalized version in a `for` loop:

```
items <- c("price", "year", "disc")

for (item in items) {
   assign(paste0(item, "list"), list.files(pattern=paste0(item, "-.*\\.txt")))
   assign(paste0(item, "df"), lapply(get(paste0(item, "list")), read.table, header=TRUE))
}

finaldf <- merge(pricedf, yeardf, by=c("longitude", "altitude"))
finaldf <- merge(finaldf, discdf, by=c("longitude", "altitude"))
```

Comment: Thanks for helping out, but how does by() work? My longitude and altitude is a list of numbers on the first row and column, can I still arrange to use the by() function?

Comment: In [merge()](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/merge.html]), `by` is the joining columns between data frames. If present in both you use the general `by` or `by.x` and `by.y` for particular df. I am not sure what you mean first row and column. Is there a column header with data rows? Please edit your post to show the data layout (simply copy and paste sample from txt file and use code format: `{}`).

Comment: Thank you! But the second assign() seems not working for read. table(), paste0(item, "list") make a file name ends with "list", but read.table() cannot recognize that character, when I type the variable by hand, read.table() recognizes it.

Comment: See my edit. Try using `get()` as `lapply()` requires an actual object and not string.