# How to convert 900 text files, that contains 2 columns, into one data frame

Tags: r, merge, text-files

I am using R and I have 900 text files that look like this. They contain two columns with 25 rows. I need to collapse them into one file that only contains two columns and 22,500 rows. I really have no idea on how to do it.

```
desk          1
chair         0.98
sofa          0.90
room          0.88
dekstop       0.88
computer      0.83
book          0.50
room          0.45
cushion       0.30
pillow        0.25
bed           0.15
bedroom       0.14
window        0.10
curtain       0.11
yard          0.11
backyard      0.11
trees         0.11
grass         0.08
tomatoes      0.07
fruits        0.05
vegetables    0.05
vitamin       0.05
sun           0.02
moon          0.02
sky           0.02
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

John Doe's answer would also work on MacOS (*e.g.* [How to open and use the Terminal app on a Mac computer](https://www.businessinsider.com/how-to-open-terminal-on-mac)) using **`cat *.txt > merged.txt`**

You probably would need to use the `cd` command to "Change Directory" to where your files are.

Note: Various MacOS use different "shells", see Apple support:

- [MacOS Catalina 10.15](https://support.apple.com/guide/terminal/open-or-quit-terminal-apd5265185d-f365-44cb-8b09-71a064a42125/mac)
- [MacOS Mojave 10.14](https://support.apple.com/guide/terminal/open-or-quit-terminal-apd5265185d-f365-44cb-8b09-71a064a42125/2.9/mac/10.14)
- [MacOS High Sierra 10.13](https://support.apple.com/guide/terminal/access-the-shell-apd5265185d-f365-44cb-8b09-71a064a42125/2.8/mac/10.13)

With a little more search there are StackOverflow solution within R but the commands proposed by John Doe within a command-line terminal are simpler and easier to use.

One example of R-based method in Stack Overflow:

- [How can I merge multiple text files into one data.frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33068861/how-can-i-merge-multiple-text-files-into-one-data-frame)
- [Creating a data frame with the contents of multiple txt files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39937310/creating-a-data-frame-with-the-contents-of-multiple-txt-files)

And more can be found from a web search...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that all files are in 1 directory.

[Windows command](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/chusedos.htm): `type *.txt > merged.txt`

[Linux command](https://www.lifewire.com/ways-to-open-a-terminal-console-window-using-ubuntu-4075024) : `cat *.txt > merged.txt`

Using R, check [this](https://psychwire.wordpress.com/2011/06/03/merge-all-files-in-a-directory-using-r-into-a-single-dataframe/)

Comment: I am sorry, but where am I suppose to type this?

Comment: Added links to open a terminal in Windows or Linux